# Convert List<Model> to List<String[]> Java for write to csv using opencsv

Tags: java, list, arraylist, opencsv

How do i put this listproduct

```
List<GetProductModel> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();
```

GetProductModel

```
private String ProductName,Description,Price; //getter and setter
```

to this list

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

so i can put list to

```
try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\test\\monitor.csv"))) {
        writer.writeAll(list);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I posted an easy approach in the answers.

Comment: If you have a method `String[] toStringArray(ProductModel product)`, then `listProduct.stream().map(e -> toStringArray(product)).toList()`. The `toStringArray` method should be trivial and is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you use for loop or Streams like:

```java
List<String[]> list = listProduct.stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(getProductModel -> new String[]{getProductModel.getProductName(), getProductModel.getDescription(), getProductModel.getPrice()})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<GetProductModel> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();

List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(GetProductModel x : listProduct) {
    String[] tmpArray = new String[3];
    tmpArray[0] = x.getProductName();
    tmpArray[1] = x.getDescription();
    tmpArray[2] = x.getPrice();
    list.add(tmpArray);
}
```

Comment: the simplest code for convert, thanks. but there is a comma after i put the list to the opencsv

Answer (score 0):

Write to csv using Java stream API, Lambda mapping and PrintWriter:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GetProductModel getProductModel = new GetProductModel();
        getProductModel.setProductName("ProductName");
        getProductModel.setDescription("Description");
        getProductModel.setPrice("Price");

        GetProductModel getProductModel2 = new GetProductModel();
        getProductModel2.setProductName("ProductName2");
        getProductModel2.setDescription("Description2");
        getProductModel2.setPrice("Price2");

        GetProductModel getProductModel3 = new GetProductModel();
        getProductModel3.setProductName("ProductName3");
        getProductModel3.setDescription("Description3");
        getProductModel3.setPrice("Price3");

        List<GetProductModel> getProductModels = new ArrayList<>();
        getProductModels.add(getProductModel);
        getProductModels.add(getProductModel2);
        getProductModels.add(getProductModel3);

        writeToFileUsingPrintWrite(getProductModels);

        writeToFileUsingCSVWriter(getProductModels);
    }

    private static void writeToFileUsingPrintWrite(List<GetProductModel> getProductModels) {
        List<String> productsList = getProductModels
                .stream()
                .map(p -> p.getProductName() + "," + p.getDescription() + "," + p.getPrice())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        File csvOutputFile = new File("C:\\products.csv");
        try (
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(csvOutputFile)) {
            productsList
                    .forEach(pw::println);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFileUsingCSVWriter(List<GetProductModel> getProductModels) {
        Iterable<String[]> productsList = getProductModels
                .stream()
                .map(p -> new String[]{p.getProductName(), p.getDescription(), p.getPrice()})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        CSVWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\products_2.csv"));
            writer.writeAll(productsList);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it really work. but that i want is using opencsv

Comment: Added implementation using OpenCSV too